# How to use $('<li>') as a jquery selector?

Tags: jquery, html

I found a strange jquery selector using html tag declaration and not just the tag name : `$('<li />')` and i couldn't find such as selector in the [jquery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/) nor in the [W3C reference](http://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_selectors.asp) for it.

this is the piece of code where i found it (it's used to create a new list item to be appended to an unrodred list)

```
$title.on("keyup", e => {
    const title = e.target.value;

    console.log('typed value : ' + title);

    getItems(title)
        .then(items => {
            $results.empty();

            const $items = items.map(item => $('<li />').text(item));
            $results.append($items);
        })
})
```

Please , i need to know more about such as selector (or if it's not a selector but a way to create new components) and its role.

Comment: It is for creating new LI element, it isn't a CSS selector, just read the relevant [DOC](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#creating-new-elements)

Comment: @Baredelman try my answer to general multiple li inside a ul dynamically
http://stackoverflow.com/a/39305209/6608101

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's not a selector. It's used for [creating new elements](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery2) in a well-looking way!

> **Description**: Creates DOM elements on the fly from the provided string of raw HTML.

For example, you can write:

```
$('<div></div>')
    .addClass('myclass')
    .attr('id', 'myid')
    .append($('<span></span>')
                .text('Hi there')
                .css('color', 'red'))
    .appendTo('body');
```

this code snippet creates the following element

```
<div id='myid' class='myclass'>
    <span style='color: red'>
        Hi there
    </span>
</div>
```

and appends it to the body.

Comment: i also wished to find the official doc but it seems your good example is enough to resume it all

Answer (score 0):

Try this following snippet to create multiple li inside a ul.

```js
$('button').click(function(){
  var ul = $('<ul>Menu</ul>');
  var li="";
  for(var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     li += "<li>"+i+"</li>";
  }
  $('body').append(ul.append(li));
  console.log($('li').length);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Generate HTML</button>
```